# Replace the word if it contains certain characters

Tags: python

I have a text file looks like :

```
a Project[2] 
novel Project[2] 
technique Project[2]
for Project[3] 
extracting Project[3] 
tables Project[3] 
from Project[3] 
lists Project[3]
```

I need to replace the `Project[x]` to `o`.

expected output:

```
a o
novel o 
technique o
for o 
extracting o 
tables o 
from o 
lists o
```

instead of using

```
.replace('Project[2],'o')
.replace('Project[3],'o')
```

is there a better way to replace if it contains `Project[x]`?

Comment: ```.replace(f'Project[{i}]', 'o')``` where `ì` is an index. Or use regex

Comment: This is a case for a regular expression (aka regex). You can craft and test out a regular expression via https://regex101.com/. The Python documentation on it is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex :

```
import re

text = """a Project[2] 
novel Project[2] 
technique Project[2]
for Project[3] 
extracting Project[3] 
tables Project[3] 
from Project[3] 
lists Project[3]"""


print(re.sub(r'Project\[\d+\]', 'o', text))
```

output :

```
a o 
novel o 
technique o
for o 
extracting o 
tables o 
from o 
lists o
```